# How to avoid "doesn't return a value on all code paths" warning without using a list iterator?

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings

Say I have an object containing a value. I wish to get the index of object with a particular value from a list of objects. I use the below code to do it,

```
int MyClass::getIndex(list& somelist, int requiredValue)
{

    for( i=0; i != somelist.count(); ++i)
    {

        if(somelist.at(i)->value() == requiredValue)
            return i;
        else
            continue;
    }

return -1;
}
```

How to avoid the "doesn't return a value on all code paths" warning without using an iterator?

Comment: This code does not produce that warning. Why did you edit your code to render the question completely nonsensical?

Comment: OP: You added the  `return -1` didn't you?

Comment: yes i did... but I still believe that the else part doesn't return a value... am I wrong? let me test it.

Comment: The else part is completely redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return T from the function in any case. If the value possibly does not exists in the list you have options:

1. return default value (nullptr for pointer for example, -1 for integer possibly)
2. use `boost::optional<T>`
3. return end iterator:

   ```
   std::list<int>::iterator find_something(std::list<int> &my_list)
   {
        for (auto it = my_list.begin(); it != my_list.end(); ++it)
        { 
            if (cond)
            {
                return it;
            }
        }

        return my_list.end();
   }
   ```

**Also**

If you just want to find the iterator to some value, use `std::find`:

```
auto it = std::find(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), my_value);
```

**Finally**

Don't use list if you need access by index. Use vector in that case

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is the same as the answer to "What do you want to happen when the element is not found?".